# Find the reviewer with the most reviews that are below the average rating for places

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We have 2 tables:

1. places
2. reviews

example of table details

```
CREATE TABLE places (   
id INT,     
name varchar(255),  
address varchar(255),   
type varchar(255),  
average_rating INT,     
price_point varchar(255),   
total reviews INT,
PRIMARY KEY id); 

INSERT INTO places VALUES  
('1', 'Hairs to You',   '45-45', 'Queens Boulevard',    'Beauty', '4.9',    '$$$',  '36'), 
('2',  'Doggonit!',      '100',   'Atlantic Ave',      'Pet Store', '3.1',  '$$',   '52'),
('3', 'Abra Kebabra',    '193',    'Sauthoff Way',  'Restaurant',   '3.3',  '$',    '315');
```

```
CREATE TABLE reviews (  
id INT,     
user_name varchar(255),     
place_id varchar(255),  
review_date DATE,   
rating INT,     
note varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY id,
FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES Places(id)
);

INSERT INTO reviews VALUES 
('149', '@pinkdeb',     '8',    '2019-07-25',   '4',    'Nice little place to grab a drink'),
('117', '@ahohl',       '16',   '2019-07-29',   '3',    'The produce is always bad but otherwise okay'),
('119', '@sammyantha',  '8',    '2019-07-30',   '4',    'LOVE how kitschy this place is! Bring your visiting friends');
```

**I would like to find the reviewer with the most reviews that are below the average rating for places.**

Do you think that it is the right code?

```
SELECT username, name, COUNT(*)
FROM reviews
CROSS JOIN places
  ON places.id = reviews.place_id
  WHERE rating < average_rating
  GROUP BY username
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

I would like to get help in case it is wrong.

Comment: How would you write it? Could you please help ?

Comment: Can you provide the `Create Table ...` statements for the two tables and a few `Insert Into ...` sample data rows, and describe the expected result based on those test data rows? See also [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
SELECT user_name, Count(ID) FROM Reviews
WHERE Rating < (SELECT Avg(Rating) AR FROM Reviews)
GROUP BY user_name
ORDER BY Count(ID) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Your CREATE TABLE SQL errors on the PRIMARY KEY assignment so I just removed that part for testing. Could probably use some more sample data but when I try to add data rows, Fiddle errors.
[MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2d1b0/9)